# How to make datetime already saved in database timezone aware in a Django project

Tags: python, django, datetime, timezone

We had a couple of timezone unaware datetime in model definition which resulted in saving a number of entries that were naive datetimes.

The default was set to be utcnow like this

```
time_sent = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.utcnow, blank=True)
```

And we got a lot of these

```
RuntimeWarning: DateTimeField ModelName.time_sent received a naive datetime (2021-08-18 06:43:04.448875) while time zone support is active.
```

We now have set the default as timezone.now so going forward we should not have this problem. However, what should we do to change the data already in database? Any ideas?

EDIT:
Found the answer.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/i18n/timezones/#migration-guide

So if you are using anything except postgres backend, this change is enough since there is no timezone information saved in db if data already in UTC.

Comment: Show the code(probably views) that raised this warning.

Comment: The warning was raised because naive datetime was being passed onto it as default. Value was not set in the views but as the default in the model field.